# JMS Connection Closed Exception in Glassfish

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, glassfish-3

My application uses EJBs deployed in Glasssfish AS which send and receive JMS messages.
There is container managed transaction throughout the application.
The stateless EJB that does the JMS part is used by many other EJBs in my app , is as below:

```java
@Stateless
Class BeanJmsHandling{

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:app/amqcfp")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
      connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      connection.start();
    }

    public void sendRx(){

     //check connection is valid , if not re-open. 

     //init session.
      session=connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     Queue q=session.createTemporaryQueue();
     MessageConsumer mc= session.createConsumer(temporaryQueue);
     //passing this queue name to an "rmi service" , that sends response on this queue.
     rmiService(q.getQueueName());
     //read from queue
     ObjectMessage m = (ObjectMessage) m.receive(30000); 
     //close session.
      session.close();

}

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeConnection()
    {
     //close the connection
     }

}
```

Here the connection is kept open with in SLSB , so to avoid the overhead of opening and closing it every time.
Often there are errors reported below in logs:

```
[#|2013-09-02T15:12:54.450+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jta|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JTS5041: The resource manager is doing work outside a global transaction
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The connection is already closed
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.toXAException(TransactionContext.java:779)
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.setXid(TransactionContext.java:687)
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.start(TransactionContext.java:370)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction.start(LocalAndXATransaction.java:136)
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionState.startAssociation(TransactionState.java:311)
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:639)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistXAResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:1314)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistComponentResources(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:1336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.postInvoke(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionInvocationHandler.beforePostInvoke(TransactionInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2021)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy293.getParameter(Unknown Source)
    .......
    .......
    Caused by: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionClosedException: The connection is already closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1462)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosedOrFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1449)
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.setXid(TransactionContext.java:684)
    ... 313 more

[#|2013-09-02T15:13:30.495+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jtsxa|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JTS5067: Unexpected error occurred in commit
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The connection is already closed
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.toXAException(TransactionContext.java:779)
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.commit(TransactionContext.java:588)
    at org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction.commit(LocalAndXATransaction.java:85)
    at com.sun.jts.jtsxa.OTSResourceImpl.commit_one_phase(OTSResourceImpl.java:174)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.RegisteredResources.commitOnePhase(RegisteredResources.java:1565)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.commitOnePhase(TopCoordinator.java:2956)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorTerm.commit(CoordinatorTerm.java:321)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TerminatorImpl.commit(TerminatorImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentImpl.commit(CurrentImpl.java:633)
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.commitDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy278.getData(Unknown Source)
    ...
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionClosedException: The connection is already closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1462)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosedOrFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1449)
    at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.commit(TransactionContext.java:549)
    ... 83 more
|#]

[#|2013-09-02T15:13:30.504+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [commit one phase] operation.|#]

[#|2013-09-02T15:13:30.511+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB DataService, method: public java.util.List org.my.DataService.getParameter(java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)|#]

[#|2013-09-02T15:13:30.512+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5147)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901) 
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy278.getData(Unknown Source)
    .....
    .....
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5031: Exception [org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0 completed: Maybe] on Resource [commit one phase] operation.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.commitDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
    ... 72 more
|#]
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, could someone please guide me to understand what is going wrong.

I found below article, not clear whether JCA RA is obtained for Glassfish or not in my case.

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShouldIcacheJMSconnectionsandJMSsessions
Thanks!

Comment: The stack trace shows `$Proxy278.getData`: Please show the source. And add the full source of `BeanJmsHandling`. The interesting parts are just comments.

Comment: $Proxy278.getData is another call made  in sequence of calls and finally reaches here..

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Message-driven bean; the connection and session are managed by the container automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The callers actually using this bean in a synchronous way and so I try to send and receive using a temporary queue and synchronous receive method.Is it not proper usage to do as above?

Comment: So when the EJB is invoked, it creates a temp queue for synchronous request/reply? Please show the `init()` method, and other code; that will help.